# Comparing base table value with second table's sum of value with group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, left-join

I have two tables:

One is base table and second is transaction table. I want to compare base table value with second table's sum of value with group by.

```
Table1(T1Id,Amount1,...)

Tabe2(T2Id,T1ID,Amount2)
```

I want those rows from table 1 WHere SUM of Table2's SUM( Amount2) is greater or equal table1's Amount1.

*T1ID is in relation with both tables
* The SQL query have many joins with other table for data retriving.

Comment: You already have all you need to do in the tags you provided. You need `JOIN` combined with `GROUP BY`. What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach uses a join:

```
SELECT t1.T1Id, t1.Amount1
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.T1Id = t2.T1ID
GROUP BY
    t1.T1Id, t1.Amount1
HAVING
    SUM(t2.Amount2) >= t1.Amount1;
```

We can also try doing this via a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.T1Id, t1.Amount1
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.Amount1 <= (SELECT SUM(t2.Amount2) FROM Table2 t2
                     WHERE t1.T1Id = t2.T1ID);
```

Comment: How do i JOIN other tables ? Because it is throwing error, (I have not tried sub query because it generally work slower then JOINS )

Comment: I have answered your original question.

Comment: Your answer is perfectly working, I need some extra help If you can

Comment: If you need to do, for example, a second join, then you should be able to still aggregate as I have done, and rollup the sum the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something similar to the query below:

```
SELECT
    a.T1Id, a.Amount1, SUM(b.Amount2)
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table2 b on b.T1Id = a.T1Id
GROUP BY a.T1Id, a.Amount1
HAVING SUM(b.Amount2) >= a.Amount1;
```

Basically what the query above does is give you the ID, Amount from table 1 and the summed amount from table 2. The HAVING clause at the end of query filters out those records where the summed amount from the second table is smaller than the amount from the first one.

If you want to add further table joins to the query, you can do so by adding as many joins as you wish. I would recommend having a referenced ID for each table you are joining in the Table1 table.